# Read File Accessible Only From Script in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, sudoers

I have written a Base shell script that needs password/key which is retrieved from a file.

Base Script---Calls---Key/Password File ---Base Script does further authenticates using the key retrieved

Requirements:
1.No user should be able to get the contents of the file directly
2. Every user should be able to execute Base Script
3. Only the script should be allowed to access the contents of the file

Any other suggestions to use password/key not visible to anyone but configurable in script is welcome

Note: I tried the sudoers approach but still no success
%usersgroup ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/key/path

Answer (score 0):

What you would like is to use the **setuid** permission bit on your script. This would execute your script with the permissions of the owner of the file.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid

Unfortunately this is not allowed on script files because it leads to serious security issues. However you could use a tool like SHC to compile your script to an executable file. You could then set the compiled object to run with the permission of the file owner rather than the user running the script.